# Create GNU C File Descriptor Without File Handle

Tags: c, gnu, file-descriptor

If I want to use a physical file along with other types of streams such as a socket, I can simply convert a file handle into a file descriptor:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
        FILE *f = fopen("uniquefilename.ext", "w");
        int fd = fileno(f);
        printf("%d\n", fd);
        fclose(f);
        return 0;
}
```

Does the GNU Standard Library provide a way to obtain a physical file's descriptor directly? Something to the effect of:

```
int fd = some_call("file_name.ext", "mode");
```

It seems I need to note I am completely aware of how a descriptor is not implicitly bound to any specific file. I was misleading when I wrote "obtain a physical file's descriptor"; what I should have wrote is something like "create a descriptor enabling access to a specific physical file".

Comment: A physical file has no file descriptor.

Comment: @KeithThompson good grief

Comment: What does that mean? A file descriptor may be associated with a physical file -- for that matter, multiple file descriptors may be associated (within the same process) with a given physical file. If the `open()` call is what you're looking for, it *allocates* a new file descriptor and associates it with the specified physical file.

Comment: File descriptors don't uniquely identify specific disk files... they identify files (and other things) your program has open.  A file that isn't opened has no file descriptor, and any given file descriptor you *do* have could correspond to pretty much anything, depending what your program has opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not.

However, you can use the [`open`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open) function directly! This is part of Linux itself, not the C standard library (technically the C standard library provides a small wrapper to allow you to call it as a C function).

Example usage:

```
int fd = open("file_name.ext", O_RDWR); // not fopen
// do stuff with fd
close(fd); // not fclose
```

Note: The man page recommends including `<sys/types.h>`, `<sys/stat.h>`, and `<fcntl.h>`, and for `close` you need `<unistd.h>`. That's quite a few headers, and I don't know if they're all necessary.

Comment: Also note that Windows *doesn't have* file descriptors, except insofar as the standard library simulates them.

Comment: Thanks! I know I already usually use `unistd.h` because of `read` and `write`.

Comment: yeah i use either cygwin or debian. i stopped bothering with even installing windows sdks a long time ago

Comment: The headers may not be necessary on Linux, but you may need to include all of them if you compile on a different system.

Comment: I believe it's part of _posix_ not just linux.